# Batch Libreoffice Writer file modification

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, batch

When a family member started using Libreoffice Writer on Ubuntu they used a particular document over and over as a starting point for new documents.  Subsequently these documents were themselves used as starting points over and over for even more documents. Unfortunately the family member wasn't aware of the "Title" field for these documents.

End result, now they have hundreds of documents with bogus content in the "Title" field, all the same. Except, after they learned about this, they started fixing the Title field, so not every document has this problem. Only most of them.

Is there a command line / batch / terminal way to

1. select the offending documents
2. blank out the Title field

Doing it document by document is impractical because there are so many.

Searching ask.libreoffice.org didn't yield an answer.

Comment: Should be do-able. Start with https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/XML_File_Formats and https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#opendocumentv1.2 . I don't see how it can be automated through libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

This script (this version) seems to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   Last updated: "Sun Jul 29 23:43:59 2018"
#
# Replace "Unwanted content" with "Desired Stuff" in the document's "Title" (File->Properties->Title)
# **WARNING** Leaves original unmodified "<file>" in "<file>~". Overwrites previous "<file>~"
# modified to remember the contents of the zip archive, and zip
# every one back together
if [[ "$1" = "-d" ]] ; then
    set -x
    shift
fi
while [[ "$1" ]] ; do
    file="$1"
    shift
    contents=$(unzip -l "$file" | tail -n +4 | awk '{print $4}' | tr "\n" " ")
    dirs=$(unzip -l "$file" | tail -n +4 | awk '{print $4}' | grep / | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq)
    unzip -qq "$file"
    sed -e 's/dc:title>Unwanted content/dc:title>Desired stuff/' meta.xml >meta.xml.new
    mv -f meta.xml.new meta.xml
    mv -f "$file" "${file}~"
    zip --quiet -o "$file" -r $contents
    rm -r $contents $dirs
    cmp --quiet "$file" "${file}~"
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
        mv -f "${file}~" "$file"
    fi
done
```

Make the script, called `FixMyTitle` executable, and store in in a directory in your `$PATH`. `$HOME/bin` is good.

Then, use `find` (read `man find`) to pass the names of the files to `FixMyTitle`:

```
find $HOME -type f -name '*.odt' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 FixMyTitle
```

Later, clean up the obsolete originals by:

```
find $HOME -type f -iname '*.odt~' -delete
```

Comment: This is very close. The final version of the document does not have the embedded graphics in it. Instead there are boxes with red text saying Read Error. I'll have to see how they went about inserting these graphics.

Comment: I added Pictures to the line starting with `zip` and that works now.  the `rm` line doesn't completely work because some of the arguments are directories.

Comment: Fixed the rm line but the grep in the 2nd script does not seem to work. Researching.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Fixed file list problem (generated it dynamically). The `grep -lZ` has a lower-case ell (the letter, `l`), not the digit `1`.

Comment: @OrganicMarble could you give a pointer to your question on ask.libreoffice.org? My script might help others there.

Comment: I didn't actually ask anything there, just searched. I haven't had time to check this revision of the script yet.  Will do it later today. Thanks.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me; in fact it's worse than the first one. The 'find` script still does not find any of the documents, and the 'fix' script throws errors about unzip not being able to find documents.  Perhaps the two problems are related, although with the first rev of the `fix` script, I was able to go file by file, but I can't do that with this one.

Comment: Run it with the "`-d`" switch, capture the output, and upload it to pastebin or some filesharing site, and post the link. I'll take a look.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Now script works for me, try the new one above.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: latest version of the script - restores original file if no changes were made. Also, works.